# Drupal 8 contextual filter for date

Tags: date, filtering, drupal-8

does anybody know how to implement the view with contextual filter on date/time value? I have a content type *Event* with date field within it and need to somehow filter items within specific month. Not sure if it can even be done without special programming and if so, whether via that contextual filter (like node/) or maybe via exposed filter with list of months so user can filter items by himself??

Thanks
TC

Answer (score 0):

There exists the contextual range filter module. 
https://www.drupal.org/project/contextual_range_filter

To the time I am writing no Drupal 8 version is shown on the module page, but there are some. Have a look in the release section "View all releases". There you can filter the API version "8.x".

You can have a look into the README.txt for all the possibilities to query.
http://cgit.drupalcode.org/contextual_range_filter/plain/README.txt?id=refs/heads/8.x-1.x

A simpler solution could be to use the build in function in views
You can add special fields in the contextual filters section 
They are called:

- Created year
- Created year + month
- Created week
- Created month
- Created day
- Created date